# How to overlay a play button over a video thumbnail image?

Tags: html, css

I got some div thumbnail images. is there a way i can place the  play icon over the thumbnail image just in the **center of thumbs**(my thumbnail images has class name of ItemImage) using css (my play icon has a class name overlayicon)?

```
<div class="ItemLeft">


  <div class="Clipping">        
    <a class="ImageLink" href="/videos/id8" title="galaxy">
      <img class="ItemImage" src="/Images/video8.jpg" alt="video 8" />
      <img class="OverlayIcon" src="/Images/1.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a class="DurationInfo" onmouseover="showDuration2(this);" onmouseout="hideDuration2(this);" href="/videos/id1234"><span class="Text">51:57</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="Title"><a href="/videos/id8" title="galaxy">galaxy</a></div>

  <div class="VideoAge">1 daybefore</div>

  <div class="PlaysInfo"> broadcast 265</div>

</div>
```

my css:

```
.Item.ItemLeft, .Item.ItemMiddle, .Item.ItemRight
{
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.clear
{
    clear:both;
}


img.ItemImage {
    width: 18em;
    height: 10em;
 }


.OverlayIcon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 65px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` on your `.OverlayIcon`. For example:

```
.ImageLink {
    height: 300px;
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.ItemImage {
    height: 300px;
    width: 350px;
}
.OverlayIcon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 65px;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/9nEua/

**Update based on user1788736's first comment**

The above solution only works if all the heights are the same and fixed. You'd then need to adjust the `top` and `left` values based on the height of your playButton.png dimension.

If you could provide a jsFiddle of what you currently have (html, css, jQuery) then it's easier to adjust the positioning more accurately.

**Update based on user1788736's second comment**

I uploaded a dummy image on my server that has the same size (56px x 37px). Here's the updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/k6yAQ/1/

**Extra info based on user1788736's third comment**

When you say "how to find values for overlayicon w and h?" I assume you are actually looking for `top` and `left` value for `.OverlayIcon`. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

First of all, if you don't intend to have a function on your site that enables zooming/enlargment, just stick with `px` as unit measurement for images.

Based on your jsFiddle thumb dimension, `12em x 10em` is equivalent to `192px x 160px`.

The formula to get the `top` and `left` values for `.OverlayIcon` is as follows:

```
OverlayIconTop = (ItemImageHeight - OverlayIconHeight )/2
OverlayIconTop = ( 160 - 37 ) / 2 = 61.5
```

(Round to 61 or 62 since we can't have decimal for px)

```
OverlayIconLeft = (ItemImageHeight - OverlayIconHeight )/2
OverlayIconLeft = ( 192 - 56 ) / 2 = 68
```

Comment: here is the fiddle i want those red play icon in middle of each thumb.http://jsfiddle.net/k6yAQ/

Comment: Can you update the play button image? It's not showing up due to restricted access. "403 - Forbidden". If not, what's the image dimension?

Comment: i don't know why it doesn't show in your side but the dimension is :56px × 37px . is there any other image hosting that i can upload it there ?

Comment: Many thanks it worked well but if change the thumb size like beleow how to find values for overlayicon w and h? img.ItemImage {
  width: 12em;
  height: 10em;
 }

Answer (score 6):

```
.container{
   position: relative;
   width: 200px;
}

.container img{
   width: 200px;
}

.container .play-icon{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top : 50%;
  left : 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

svg:hover #play-svg{
  fill: #CC181E;
}
```

[Working example using svg]http://jsfiddle.net/4L2xea4u/

Comment: works well, however I have a list of thumbnails the first one works for the hover over, but as the rest will share the same identifier they don't do the hover over, any ideas some sort of loop is needed?

Comment: @Gav change id="play-svg" to class="play-svg" on html and svg:hover #play-svg{ to svg:hover .play-svg{

Answer (score 1):

You can make the thumbnail image as the background and then have the play button image over it, you can also define the a attribute as a block and make the entire area clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrestled with this problem for a responsive layout and came across [this demo](http://douglasgreen.com/demo/responsive-video-play-button/) and it worked wonderfully.